# How to propagate conan's compiler.cppstd setting to the compiler when building a library with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

If you build a library with conan and set `compiler.cppstd` setting to e.g. `20` and call `conan install`, the libraries are still built with the default standard for the given compiler.

[The docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.45/howtos/manage_cpp_standard.html#build-helpers) say:

> The value of compiler.cppstd provided by the consumer is used by the build helpers:
>
> - The [CMake](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.45/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#cmake-reference) build helper will set the CONAN_CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD and CONAN_CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS definitions that will be converted to the corresponding CMake variables to activate the standard automatically with the conan_basic_setup() macro.

So it looks like you need to call `conan_basic_setup()` to activate this setting. But how do I call it? By patching a library's CMakeLists.txt? I sure don't want to do that just to have the proper standard version used. I can see some recipes that manually set the CMake definition based on the setting, e.g.:

- https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/folly/all/conanfile.py#L117
- https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/crc32c/all/conanfile.py#L58
- https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/azure-storage-cpp/all/conanfile.py#L71
- https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/caf/all/conanfile.py#L105

But this feels like a hack either. So what is the proper way to make sure libraries are built with the `compiler.cppstd` I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid patching, it's ugly and fragile, for each new release you will need an update due upstream's changes.

The main approach is a CMakeLists.txt as wrapper, as real example: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/5f77986125ee05c4833b0946589b03b751bf634a/recipes/proposal/all/CMakeLists.txt and there many others.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(cmake_wrapper)

include(conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(KEEP_RPATHS)

add_subdirectory(source_subfolder)
```

The important thing here is including `conanbuildinfo.cmake` which is generated by [cmake](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake.html) Conan generator, then the [CMake](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html) helper will do the rest.

The `source_subfolder` here is project source folder, then the main CMakeLists.txt will be loaded after configuring all Conan settings.

Comment: Thanks! Here are some links to related discussions in slack: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/10597#issuecomment-1043239643

Comment: Seems like in conan 2.0 this wrapper will no longer be necessary and CMakeToolchain will be used instead: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html

Comment: True, CMakeToolchain is the new way to go. On Conan Center Index we have examples, but we will start to migrate soon.